# "It will be determined what the consequences are" vs. "It will be determined what are the consequences"?

Tags: grammar

Which of the sentences is correct/preferred:

1. It will be determined what the consequences are.
2. It will be
       determined what are the consequences.

Is there a rule to settle the question or is it merely a preference?

Comment: The first is the correct idiomatic form. I think the point is that "the consequences" is the subject of the verb "are". And since it is not an interrogative sentence, the subject usually precedes the verb.

Comment: Hello, gilianzz. Would you say 'We found where he lives' or 'We found where lives he'?

Answer (score 1):

It varies due to context, and it *is* just a preference thing, but the second one would (usually) sound awkward.

Answer (score 0):

3: The consequences will be determined.

4: I will determine the consequences.

5: The judge will determine the consequences.

6: You will determine the consequences.

Because 1, 2, and even 3 are too indirect, positing a godlike, incomprehensible method of consequence determination.